# Is this PCIE x 4 connector of an NVMe SSD compatible with the connector of my current NVMe SSD (SATA)?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, sata, pci-express

I want to upgrade my [current stock NVMe](https://www.amazon.de/Hynix-HFS256G39TND-N210A-256GB-hynix-Client/dp/B073H93XKZ) to something like [this Samsung NVMe](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B07MBQPQ62/ref=twister_B07N1DF97S?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1). My laptop is an [Asus FX553VE](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/FX553VD/HelpDesk_Manual/).

However I am totally confused about what is compatible with my laptop and what isn't. The connector of my current NVMe is SATA according to the amazon listing, all other NVMe's I can find have a different looking (PCIe?) connector. The last comment of [this](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?103322-ASUS-FX553VE-and-NVME-Support-Verification) forum post says that I should use PCIe connectors. [The manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/GL553VW/0409_E11734_GL553VW_A.pdf) of my laptop only mentions the M.2 formfactor but no further specifics.

So my questions are:

1. Is the above mentioned samsung NVMe SSD compatible with my laptop?
2. If yes, why are the connectors named differently and why do they look different? Is the M.2 formfactor the only relevant criteria here?
3. If no, what is the exact name of my stock connector? I thought SATA connectors are the ones for bigger harddrives and SSDs. What do I have to look for when searching a compatible NVMe SSD?

Comment: “If no, what is the exact name of my stock connector?” - SATA M.2

Comment: @Ramhound Well, if I look for "SATA M.2 NVMe" I again get results with both connectors. Perhaps I should ask differently: Are all three connectors in [this](https://www.crucial.de/content/dam/crucial/support/ssd/mx200%20family.jpg.transform/medium-jpg/img.jpg) image intercompatible? My SSD has two gaps, the others only have one.

Comment: A M.2 connector can be both SATA and NVMe (PCIe) but a M.2 device can only be one or the other. Compatibly with NVMe is normally explicitly. Your laptop doesn’t explicitly indicate support for it

Comment: NVMe implies a PCI Express connection. A SATA SSD cannot be a NVMe SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be really confusing as web-shops and advertisements often are very sloppy with terminology.

When you are talking about M.2 connectors the term SATA just refers to the data-transfer protocol between motherboard and the storage device inserted in the M.2 slot.

M.2 slots can provide a SATA interface or a NVMe interface (which is essentially a PCIe 4x interface) or both.
(The main difference is speed. NVMe with 4 PCIe lanes has several times faster data-throughput than SATA.)

Older motherboards (like in your laptop) with M.2 slots ONLY provide SATA.
NVMe is available on newer motherboards.
Some (usually high-end) motherboards provide both interfaces on the M.2 connector and will automatically operate as one or the other depending on the type of SSD inserted in the slot.
(Or will fall back to SATA if not enough PCIe lanes are available because other hardware, like a 2nd video-card, is using them.)

Your laptop is an older model that only provides SATA on the M.2 connector.
A M.2 NVMe SSD will NOT be compatible with your laptop.
You will need a M.2 SATA SSD (like the original one).

M.2 SATA is also often referred to as mSATA. This is incorrect as mSATA is on older and incompatible standard that uses a mini-PCI connector in stead of the M.2 connector.
You have to keep that in mind when shopping for a compatible SSD.
*If you see mSATA mentioned double-check if it is M.2 or not.*

Finding a reasonable large M.2 SATA SSD can be difficult.
As far as I know 1 TB is the biggest size they come in.

Comment: mSATA is a different SSD connector. It looks somewhat like M.2 but it is totally incompatible. mSATA is dead.

Comment: @DanielB You are right about the original mSATA (mini-PCI formfactor with SATA signaling, slightly smaller connector than M.2). That was only short-lived. Unfortunately mSATA is now widely used as a synonym for M.2 SATA. Probably because the marketing people who write the ads and the web-shop texts don't have a clue. I will clarify that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

And additional problem you may face when upgrading to large NVMe is that even when specification and connector matches, there may not be enough physical space below or above the SSD.

Here is good [illustration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBypF80vTi0).
In this video previous SSD is single-sided and have chips only on top, while new SSD have also chips underneath which block proper placing. This is not common problem and laptop even may have one slot with double-sided support and other completely similar but without extra space underneath. When buying large NVMe for laptop options are:

- to ensure that you can return it back even after unpack
- or to ensure that someone already successfully installed double-sided
- or to ensure that you buy single-sided

Large radiator on top of NVMe can also cause same type of problem.